# auto update /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have some error doing sudo apt-get dist-upgrade so I resolve it by changing all reference to trusty in my /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade to xenial, my actual ubuntu desktop version.

Why this is not doing automatically during system updating?
It is right to me resolve the problem manually updating the /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade?

regards,
Leonardo